# Postgres at time zone '+07' syntax

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I recently had some troubles with timestamptz in postgres. I now understand that time is always saved as utc in the database and what is inserted and fetched depend on what is set up in the connection. [This](http://blog.untrod.com/2016/08/actually-understanding-timezones-in-postgresql.html) blog post helped clear much of the original confusion.

But I still ran into some weirdness, when searching for syntax that is safe regardless of the timezone the connection has:

```
postgres=# show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)

postgres=# select '2000-01-01 00:00:00+07' at time zone 'GMT+07', '2000-01-01 00:00:00+07' at time zone 'Asia/Jakarta';
      timezone       |      timezone       
---------------------+---------------------
 1999-12-31 10:00:00 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)

postgres=# select current_timestamp, current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT+07', current_timestamp at time zone 'Asia/Jakarta';
              now              |          timezone          |          timezone          
-------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 2018-01-29 06:17:07.845564+00 | 2018-01-28 23:17:07.845564 | 2018-01-29 13:17:07.845564
(1 row)
```

So the version with `'Asia/Jakarta'` works as expected, but the `'+7'`, `'+07'`, `'GMT+07'` and `'UTC+07'` gives me the expected timestamp minus 14 hours.

Why does this happend and what is the correct way to convert timestamptz to different time zones that works independently of the connections time zone?